# Writing filenames from a folder into a csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to parse all files in a folder and write the filenames in a CSV using Python. The code I used is

```
import os, csv

f=open("C:/Users/Amber/weights.csv",'r+')
w=csv.writer(f)
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/Amber/Creator"):
    for filename in files:
        w.writerow(filename)
```

The result I'm getting in the CSV has individual alphabets in one column rather than the entire row name. How to fix that?

Comment: shouldn't you open the file in 'w' mode?

Comment: Your code has a numbero of other issues. First of all, if you are not reading from a file, you don't need `r+` mode, use `w`. Also when working with files you should always be using `with` statement.

Comment: @kirelagin I m relatively new to python and file handling in general, i ll keep that in mind for future codes.

Comment: "for filename in files:" - this is weird bit. You could use w.writerow(files) to get a list of comma separated filenames

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import os, csv

f=open("C:/Users/Amber/weights.csv",'r+')
w=csv.writer(f)
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/Amber/Creator"):
    for filename in files:
        w.writerow([filename])
```

Comment: on using this it inserted with one row gap in between how can that be avoided ? NOTE: I used `w+`. @falsetru

Comment: @Rex5, I don't understand your question. BTW, if you use `w+` mode, file is truncated.

Comment: Sry for unclear comment, I meant that when I used `w+` the purpose of question is solved, but in Excel sheet the entries are made leaving one row blank in between two entries. Like first entry in `A1` then second entry in `A3` and so on a5 a7... Although it's quite easy to remove those blank rows, yet I wanted to know why is that. @falsetru thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rex5, I suggest you to post a separate question with your code that reproduce the issue.

Comment: OK, am trying to resolve that first and if not able to get it will tag you in the new question.

Answer (score 6):

`writerow()` expects a sequence argument:

```
import os, csv

with open("C:/Users/Amber/weights.csv", 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/Amber/Creator"):
        for filename in files:
            writer.writerow([filename])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import glob
with open('csvinput.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    a = glob.glob('filepath/*.png')
    writer.writerows(zip(a)) #if you need the results in a column
```

Comment: Please, make sure that you explain the code you post.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

     datapath = open('output.csv", 'w')
     folderpath = 'C:\\Users\\kppra\\Desktop\\Data'

     for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(folderpath,topdown=True):
          for f in files:
          datapath.write(f)
          datapath.write('\n')
datapath.close()
```

Comment: Your filename `'output.csv"` has mismatched quotes, and is messing up the formatting for the rest of the code.