# How to write into a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I want to write all the file names into a comma-separated csv file.

I have tried this, but it separates all the characters, not only the whole file names.

```
for filename in filenames:
    with open('C:\Users\igyulavics\Desktop\estfile.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        a = (os.path.join(dirname, filename))
        print a
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(a)
    csvFile.close()
```

So it gives back:

```
c,Users,1,
```

etc. but I want:

```
c:\Users\1,c:\Users\2
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981303/writing-filenames-from-a-folder-into-a-csv

Comment: There is a [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Please provide a sample of `estfile.csv`

Answer (score 0):

How are the filenames stored inside your file?  If it is coming back as you describe you can try to use some concatenation in your join and make a new as `(os.path.join(':\', dirname, '\',filename)`

Answer (score 0):

Like the post above, you should reconsider how `a` is stored.

Further, the way your code is written, it overwrites the output file in every for loop iteration. I guess you'd like the output in only one file, so you could store the filenames first and then write it to the csv. For example:

```
new_list = []
for filename in filenames:
    a = (os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    new_list.append(a)

with open('C:\Users\igyulavics\Desktop\estfile.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
     writer.writerows(new_list)
csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
with open('C:\Users\igyulavics\Desktop\estfile.csv', 'w') as csvFile:   
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    for filename in filenames:                     #Iterate Each line
        a = (os.path.join(dirname, filename))      #Full Path
        print a
        writer.writerow([a])                       #Write ROW. writerow instead of  writerows
```